# Magento Easylife Switcher

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I use this Magento extension: Easylife Switcher, i have a question maybe someone can help me with this, is there anyway to enlarge the color swatch / that small attribute on mouse over? and I want to display the label of the selected attribute too.

Thank you[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the size of the thumbnails from the [configuration section](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/wiki/configuration).
There is a field called `Label / Options image size`.
As for the label of the selected option, you may need to modify the js that changes the dropdown to labels or images.
The attribute option label is already there as an `alt` for the image. You could add a span with the option label below the image.
The image is generated [in here](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/blob/master/js/easylife_switcher/product.js#L165) for custom images and [in here](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/blob/master/js/easylife_switcher/product.js#L177) for simple product images.
The variable `text` in those lines represent the option label you are looking for.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer, can you help me with some code?

Comment: I already gave you the lines you need to modify. Try it first and see what happens.

Comment: thank you marius but my question is how to add that mouse over on the image? i see where the image is generated, but how can i add a mouse over event on this image?

Comment: aaah. I get it now. You need to attach a zoomer to the options. and that depends on your zoomer

Comment: yes, so when I put the mouse over option images I need something to display that option image, to by much bigger

Comment: so is impossible?

Comment: is not impossible, but It requires a lot of code that is theme specific and I don't know the code you need.

Comment: so this cannot be done in the file that you show me? in product.js? to add there a span and some events? to be independent of theme?

Comment: Yes. you can edit that file, but I don't know the code you need to put in there, after the `img` tags are generated. You have to figure that out by yourself.

Comment: maybe someone who know javascript can handle with this? i don't know javascript, only for this i post it here, maybe someone can help me